# add unique code required to register

Tags: customization, forms, user-registration

I have a custom registration form on my homepage and I want to add a field where a code has to be put in to allow people to register. So that only people i give the code to can register.

I believe it'd be as simple as adding a 1+2= ? validation to the form, but i can't even find any info on that.

Let me know if anyone has any ideas. Thanks.

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post') ?>" method="post"> 

            <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" class="input"  onfocus="if(this.value == 'Username'){this.value = '';}" type="text" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Username';}" value="Username" />


            <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" class="input"  onfocus="if(this.value == 'Email Address'){this.value = '';}" type="text" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Email Address';}" value="Email Address" />

                <?php do_action('register_form'); ?>  
                <input type="submit" value="Register" id="register" />  

            <p class="statement">A password will be e-mailed to you.</p>  


            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a field on your registration form

```
<label for="secret_reg_code">Secret Code: </label>
<input type="text" name="secret_reg_code" id="secret_reg_code" value="" />
```

then in your plugin file or in function.php add

```
define('MY_SECRET_REG_CODE', 'fdsfgadsfgdf');

function check_for_reg_secret_code($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {
  if (
    defined('MY_SECRET_REG_CODE') &&
    trim($_POST['secret_reg_code']) != MY_SECRET_REG_CODE
  ) {
    $errors->add(
      'secret_code_error',
      __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Enter a valid code postal code.', 'your_text_domain')
    );
  }
  return $errors;
}
add_filter('registration_errors', 'check_for_reg_secret_code', 10, 3);
```

A more 'flexible' way is use [WP Settings Api](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) to create an option 'secret_reg_code' where to store the secret code and then the function became:

```
function check_for_reg_secret_code($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {
  $code = get_option('secret_reg_code');
  if ( $code && trim($_POST['secret_reg_code']) != $code) {
    ...
```

In this way is easy change code periodically.

For more details see [Codex for `registration_errors` filter hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_errors)

### Edit

To add the field on the standard registration form is possible to use the `register_form` hook:

```
function add_secret_code_registration_field() {
    ?>
    <p>
    <label for="secret_reg_code">Secret Code<br />
    <input type="text" name="secret_reg_code" id="secret_reg_code" class="input" value="" size="25" /></label>
    </p>
    <?php
}
add_action('register_form','add_secret_code_registration_field');
```

Comment: So this works on the custom register form, how would I go about adding the field to the wp-login.php register form

Comment: @OneEightLeft see the edit

Comment: so it worked before I added the field to my wp-login page. Now it doesn't work in my index.php and redirects to my wp-login then i put the code in there and it works.

Comment: if you want to see it in action i've pushed it live to www.kevinmonahan.com/test/ and the invite code 238m3d3vac

Comment: In your custom login form you manually add the input field for secret code? Once you have `do_action('register_form');` in your custom login form, then if you put the `add_secret_code_registration_field` in your functions.php you do not need to add the field in the custom form: the action will do it for you. And it should works for both standard wp-login and for your custom login.